# Нужна помощь в разработке приложения WPF

Tags: wpf

Я разрабатываю учебное приложение "Конструктор тестов" на wpf используя паттерн проектирования MVVM, нынешний тестовый вариант нарушает его концепцию и мне не удаётся найти решение как это можно исправить. Проблема заключается в том что в классе MainWindowViewModel есть ObservableCollection Questions в которой храниться элементы Question, коллекция определена типом object так как класс Question дженерик и я не могу нормально его указать как дженерик параметр коллекции, чтобы обращаться к определенному элементу коллекции было создано поле selectedControlQuestion в которое должно передаваться значение из ListBox x:Name="Questions", после чего я смог бы обращаться к полям класса Question используя это поле, но при поиске элемента в коллекции и выполнения различных действий по типу remove выдаться ошибка, поэтому некоторые команды были вынесены в класс Question, что нарушает потерн проектирования. Сильно усложняет задачу то что у меня есть коллекция которая хранит класс Question, также сам класс Question тоже имеет свою коллекцию и обе эти коллекции выводиться на экран и могут динамически изменяться в зависимости от действий пользователя, именно эта особенность моего подхода приносит мне много неудобств, хотелось ее как-то изменить но ничего лучше придумать не удаётся. Хочется узнать ваше мнения по тому как изменить код так, чтобы я мог без проблем создавать множество вопросов с множеством вариантов ответов и притом чтобы была возможность пользователю динамических их изменять, без нарушения потерна проектирования.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckedItemSelector" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextItemSelector">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding CorrectAnswer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="100"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonItemSelector" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    
        <vm:QuestionsDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBox Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button  x:Name="Create" Content="Один из списка" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateQuestionCheckBoxItems}"/>
                <Button x:Name="CreateText" Content="Множество из списка" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateQuestionRadioButtomItems}"/>
                <Button x:Name="CreateCheck" Content="Текс" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateQuestionTextItem}"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <ListBox x:Name="Questions" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}"
                     SelectedIndex ="{Binding SelectedControlQuestion}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding QuestionName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Button Content="Удалить вопрос" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding RemoveQuestions}" >
                                <Button.DataContext>
                                    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
                                </Button.DataContext>
                            </Button>
                            <ListBox x:Name="AnswersItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}"
                                     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button  x:Name="Add" Content="Add" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding AddItem}"/>
                                <Button  x:Name="Remove" Content="Remove" Width="50" 
                Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding RemoveItem}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel      
    {
        public ObservableCollection<object> Questions { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<object>();

         private int selectedControlQuestion;
         public int SelectedControlQuestion
         {
             get => selectedControlQuestion;
             set => Set(ref selectedControlQuestion, value);
         }
 

        private LambdaCommands removeQuestions;
        public LambdaCommands RemoveQuestions
        {
            get
            {
                return removeQuestions ??
                  (removeQuestions = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      Questions.RemoveAt(selectedControlQuestion);
                  }));
            }
        }

        private LambdaCommands createQuestionCheckBoxItems;
        public LambdaCommands CreateQuestionCheckBoxItems
        {
            get
            {
                return createQuestionCheckBoxItems ??
                  (createQuestionCheckBoxItems = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      var questionCheckBoxItem = new Question<CheckBoxItem>();
                      questionCheckBoxItem.Answers.Add(new CheckBoxItem());
                      Questions.Add(questionCheckBoxItem);
                  }));
            }
        }

        private LambdaCommands createQuestionRadioButtomItems;
        public LambdaCommands CreateQuestionRadioButtomItems
        {
            get
            {
                return createQuestionRadioButtomItems ??
                  (createQuestionRadioButtomItems = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      var questionRadioButtom = new Question<RadioButtomItem>();
                      questionRadioButtom.Answers.Add(new RadioButtomItem());
                      Questions.Add(questionRadioButtom);
                  }));
            }
        }

        private LambdaCommands createQuestionTextItem;
        public LambdaCommands CreateQuestionTextItem
        {
            get
            {
                return createQuestionTextItem ??
                  (createQuestionTextItem = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      var questionText = new Question<TextItem>();
                      questionText.Answers.Add(new TextItem());
                      Questions.Add(questionText);
                  }));
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

```
public class Question<T> : ViewModel
        where T : IItem, new()
    {
        private string questionName = "text";
        public string QuestionName
        {
            get => questionName;
            set => Set(ref questionName, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<T> Answers { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        private T selectedItem;
        public T SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        #region Command
        private LambdaCommands addItem;
        public LambdaCommands AddItem
        {
            get
            {
                return addItem ??
                  (addItem = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      T item = new T();
                      Answers.Add(item);
                  }));
            }
        }

        private LambdaCommands removeItem;
        public LambdaCommands RemoveItem
        {
            get
            {
                return removeItem ??
                  (removeItem = new LambdaCommands(obj =>
                  {
                      Answers.Remove(selectedItem);
                  }));
            }
        }  
        #endregion
    }
```

```
public class CheckBoxItem : ViewModel, IItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => Set(ref text, value);
        }

        private bool correctAnswer;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => Set(ref correctAnswer, value);
        }
    }
```

```
public class RadioButtomItem : ViewModel, IItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => Set(ref text, value);
        }

        private bool correctAnswer;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => Set(ref correctAnswer, value);
        }
    }
```

```
public class TextItem : ViewModel, IItem
    {
        private string correctAnswer;
        public string CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => Set(ref correctAnswer, value);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]